# Merge Sort is running far too slow in Java

Tags: java, performance, merge, mergesort

I'm writing a merge sort to compare to various other types of sorts, and for some reason it's running a lot slower than is to be expected. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void merge (E[] array, int leftBottom, int leftTop, int rightBottom, int rightTop){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] middleMan = (E[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length+1);

    int leftFlag = leftBottom;
    int rightFlag = rightBottom;
    int flag = leftBottom;
    int elements = (rightTop - leftBottom + 1);

    while ((leftFlag <= leftTop) && (rightFlag <= rightTop)){
        if (array[leftFlag].compareTo(array[rightFlag])<=0){
            middleMan[flag++] = array[leftFlag++];
        }
        else{
            middleMan[flag++] = array[rightFlag++];
        }
    }

    while (leftFlag <= leftTop){
        middleMan[flag++] = array[leftFlag++];
    }

    while (rightFlag <= rightTop){
        middleMan[flag++] = array[rightFlag++];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
        array[rightTop] = middleMan[rightTop];
        rightTop--;
    }
}
```

I suspect the reason is because "middleMan" is being created at the same size as "array" no matter how small I get recursively, but I can't figure out any other way to do it (including using rightTop - leftBottom + 1 as the length, which returns an error). Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: This is a bit difficult to read.

Comment: You want me to edit it? Sorry about that, not sure how to make it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your "returns an error" is `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you index `middleMan` from `flag` equals to `leftBottom` initially, which could be far beyond `elements` size: say you are merging elements from 100 to 103, `elements` is 4, `flag` = `leftBottom` = 100.

To fix this, allocate `middleMan` (of the same size you currently do) just once outside of all recursive `merge` calls,  and pass this temporary array as an extra arg of this method.